# Yeoman generator throws the error "Object has no method 'templatePath'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman

I'm starting create my own yeoman generator.

According this [article](http://yeoman.io/authoring/file-system.html), I want to write some content to the html file. I use the following code:

```
writing: function() {
    this.fs.copyTpl(
        this.templatePath("index.html"),
        this.destinationPath("public/index.html"),
            { title: "My template" }
    );
}
```

But when I run my generator, I have the error : `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'templatePath'`

My yeoman version is 1.4.7 and yeoman-generator version is 0.17.7

Comment: Did you solved this? I have the same problem

Comment: No, I did not... unfortunately

Comment: @Javier Manzano JFYI: I've created the issue on github - https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/826

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method is only available starting at `yeoman-generator 0.18`. Update the version you're using.